# Can I boot my 2011 MacBook Air from an external SSD (OS X, Windows and/or Linux)?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, external-disk

I have a mid-2011 MAcBook Air which I just upgraded the SSD in.  The old SSD had a windows install which I have been unable to clone onto the new SSD (perhaps that is the solution I am looking for ...).

Ideally, I would like to boot Win 10 from the external SSD - is this possible and if so can you point me to the right methods to get the current partition acting as a bootable drive?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the old drive in an external drive case then connect it to your Mac and the hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key at boot. The Mac will then give you the option to select the boot drive.